# null check of function pointer doesn't work

Tags: c, if-statement, null

I have a code

```c
void(*updateFunc)(EW_Window*) = ((GlfwWindow*)wnd->wndData)->updateCallback;
if (updateFunc)
    updateFunc(wnd);
```

And `if (updateFunc)` always passes even `updateFunc` is *0xcdcdcd* (null in debugger).
What's going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: That is some special pattern to indicate usage of uninitialized variables. Check where you get that function pointer from and search for cases where you don't assign a value. In your case: Check where `updateCallback` should have been set. For people at SO to help you, you will most likely need to show a bit more code to reproduce how you end up with such an invalid pointer.

Comment: Just to be sure, you know `->` takes precedence over casts, right? So you are casting wndData to a pointer, not wnd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xcdcdcd` is not null-pointer, it is a pattern used to mark unitialized memory. That value is considered as a `true` value in C. The problem is that `((GlfwWindow*)wnd->wndData)->updateCallback` has a wrong value...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
void(*updateFunc)(EW_Window*) = ((GlfwWindow*)wnd )->wndData->updateCallback;
```